# What specific acts with a nidah constitute karet

Tags: niddah, karet

I'm new and starting out. But karet sounds serious. Is it just the standard intimate relationship  that gives karet or does  unnatural and  other practices as well. What about kissing or other non penetrative relationship. One rabbi told me even touching a women who is nidah gives karet.

Comment: `Is there a way to mitigate this punishment` This seems like a separate question. Consider asking it separately.

Comment: This question might fall afoul of our modesty policy http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29930/759

Comment: The Rabbi probably ment touching is biblically forbidden, and it can lead to karet , in the way explained in the answer below

Comment: Kareit doesn't seem like a sufficient metric for figuring out what's serious

Comment: @DoubleAA I also asked myself about modestly the language is from a low level of life.

Comment: @DoubleAA Not going to push this, but Jewishly-speaking, isn't possibly keeping someone from doing a kareit-level (and according to you possibly death-level) sin way more important than one arguable occurrence of pritzus?

Comment: You asked for a link for you to read http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67346/5120

Comment: A more direct source http://chabad.org/960651/ I think it is important for you to see this to http://chabad.org/960669/

Comment: You can see from these sources that (as I said above) touching does not give karet

Comment: I see no mention of other acts though(trying to keep it cleaner) specifically penetration in a higher area is not covered in any of the sources.

Answer (score 2):

#### What is Chayav Karet?

Starting Biah, which is called **heara**  (i.e. at least penetration of the glans), is defined as biah (intercourse) in Arayot (prohibited sexual relationship) rules, whether vaginal or anal, and is called by Tora mishkeve Isha (Leviticus 20, 13)<sup>[1]</sup> ("woman's lying")). We will partially demonstrate this further.

Torah told about prohibition and about punishment for who break the prohibition intentionally.

1. The verse which **prohibits** is (Leviticus 18, 19)

   > **"Also you shall not approach a woman to uncover her nakedness, as long as she is put apart for her menstrual uncleanness.".**

   "approach to uncover her nakedness is translated concerning nidda, following a part of Rishonim (Ramban at least) as regarding sexual intercourse only.
2. The verse which communicates the punishment (the  Karet) is in Leviticus18, 29

   > **For whoever shall commit any of these abominations, the souls who commit them shall be cut off from among their people.**

   1. The Karet punishment is according to everybody for sexual intercourse only. This last point is written in Misnna.
   2. The mishna said this in Kretot 1, 1 in the list of all chiuve Kretot that for  nidda intercourse is the problem:

      > ‏‏שְׁלשִׁים וָשֵׁשׁ כְּרֵתוֹת בַּתּוֹרָה. הַבָּא עַל ......  **וְעַל הַנִּדָּה**

   > There are in the torah thirty-six [transgressions which are punishable with] extinction: when one has intercourse ... with a  **menstruous woman;**
3. See a summary of the Halacha, from Sefer Chinuch 207:

   > ונוהג אסור זה בכל מקום ובכל זמן. ועובר עליה ושכב את הנדה במזיד, מכיון  **שהערה בה חיב כרת,**  בשוגג מביא חטאת קבועה. ובן הנדה אינו נקרא ממזר אלא ולד פגום. ובלאו דלא יבא ממזר נבאר זה בעזרת השם בסדר כי תצא
   >
   > This mitsva is relevant everytime. One who break this law intentionally and penetrate (at least with the glans) is punished by Karet...
4. Touching a woman nidda doesn't give Karet as the Chinuch summarized, intercourse only is concerned by karet.

---

[1] Gemara Sanhedrin 55a.

> R'Nahman, son of R'Hisda stated in an exposition: In the case of a woman, there are two modes of intimacy,

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49014/discussion-on-answer-by-kouty-what-specific-acts-with-a-nidah-constitute-karet).

Comment: @kouty "Touching a woman nidda doesn't give Karet as the Chinuch summarized, intercourse only is concerned by karet." By intercourse, do you mean both anally and vaginally?

Comment: @ninamag yes ..